# Adding a column to pandas data frame fills it with NA

Tags: python, pandas

I have this pandas dataframe:

```
          SourceDomain                           1  2         3
0  www.theguardian.com     profile.theguardian.com  1  Directed
1  www.theguardian.com  membership.theguardian.com  2  Directed
2  www.theguardian.com   subscribe.theguardian.com  3  Directed
3  www.theguardian.com            www.google.co.uk  4  Directed
4  www.theguardian.com        jobs.theguardian.com  5  Directed
```

I would like to add a new column which is a pandas series created like this:

```
Weights = Weights.value_counts()
```

However, when I try to add the new column using `edgesFile[4] = Weights` it fills it with NA instead of the values:

```
          SourceDomain                           1  2         3   4
0  www.theguardian.com     profile.theguardian.com  1  Directed NaN
1  www.theguardian.com  membership.theguardian.com  2  Directed NaN
2  www.theguardian.com   subscribe.theguardian.com  3  Directed NaN
3  www.theguardian.com            www.google.co.uk  4  Directed NaN
4  www.theguardian.com        jobs.theguardian.com  5  Directed NaN
```

How can I add the new column keeping the values?
Thanks?

Dani

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting NaNs because the index of `Weights` does not match up with the index of `edgesFile`. If you want Pandas to ignore `Weights.index` and just paste the values *in order* then pass the underlying NumPy array instead:

```
edgesFile[4] = Weights.values
```

---

Here is an example which demonstrates the difference:

```
In [14]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(4)*10, index=list('ABCD'))

In [15]: df
Out[15]: 
    0
A   0
B  10
C  20
D  30

In [16]: s = pd.Series(np.arange(4), index=list('CDEF'))

In [17]: s
Out[17]: 
C    0
D    1
E    2
F    3
dtype: int64
```

Here we see Pandas *aligning* the index:

```
In [18]: df[4] = s

In [19]: df
Out[19]: 
    0   4
A   0 NaN
B  10 NaN
C  20   0
D  30   1
```

Here, Pandas simply pastes the values in `s` into the column:

```
In [20]: df[4] = s.values

In [21]: df
Out[21]: 
    0  4
A   0  0
B  10  1
C  20  2
D  30  3
```

Comment: Thanks! It's working and I've just learned a very interesting thing. I'll accept the answer as soon as it allows me.

Answer (score 0):

This is small example of your question:

You can add new column with a column name in existing DataFrame

```
>>> df = DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], columns = ['A', 'B', 'C'])
>>> df
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6

>>> s = Series([7,8])
>>> s
0    7
1    8
2    9

>>> df['D']=s
>>> df
   A  B  C  D
0  1  2  3  7
1  4  5  6  8
```

Or, You can make DataFrame from Series and concat then

```
>>> df = DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
>>> df
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6

>>> s = DataFrame(Series([7,8]), columns=['4']) # if you don't provide column name, default name will be 0
>>> s
   0
0  7
1  8

>>> df = pd.concat([df,s], axis=1)
>>> df
   0  1  2  0
0  1  2  3  7
1  4  5  6  8
```

Hope this will help